# ERC20 contract estimates gas used

Tags: geth-debugging

I'm new in blockchain and ethereum, And I tried to transfer contract tokens and estimate needs gas(eth)

there was the error response when address ETH balance not enough

```
> eth.estimateGas({from:"0x717af978a95f60f61f6fd187001d9877fcac839b", to:"0x839419b3eec7d05d612f15106faea79e277fe790", data:"0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000444bfbe8bc521557923fdeb217ab35d760b5cf100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ac7230489e80000", gasPrice:1})
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (0)
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:16(12)
```

Is't possible to ignore this balance check and get "estimateGas" anyway?